# Joomla 2.5 duplicate session error "PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO"

Tags: mysql, sql, session, joomla

This is the message we're receiving on the frontend

`` Duplicate entry '5dcf22giahsklj52uhukcdc6k5' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `kawt1_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('5dcf22giahsklj52uhukcdc6k5', 0, '1615520883') ``

I've tried truncating the sessions table, dropping the table and then creating a new structure with the following code

```
+++===============
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kawt1_session` (
    `username` varchar(150) default '',
    `time` varchar(14) default '',
    `session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
    `guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
    `userid` int(11) default '0',
    `usertype` varchar(50) default '',
    `gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    `client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    `data` longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
    KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
    KEY `userid` (`userid`),
    KEY `time` (`time`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ===============+++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered the issue was ONLY displayed on the homepage of the website, I switched the default home page to another menu item. This resolved the problem. Now I have to understand why this only occurred on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the database and find for the jos_session table ( here "jos" is prefix so you can search with your prefix and _session table )

Select that table and Repair it, it will solve the issue. https://prnt.sc/10jrzg7

Comment: Hi I did this before posting the problem. I also optimized, repaired, truncated, and dropped nothing worked. I've now resolved the issue and answered the question